# Is there any way to use a Joomla site into an app using PhoneGap?

Tags: php, cordova, joomla

I am new in PhoneGap,

I have a Joomla Site, I want to create a PhoneGap App using that Joomla site. so is this possible ? if yes than how can i implement it ?.

Answer (score 0):

You can use. But you have to create web services for request and responses. Because Phonegap will not run PHP script. So you can create webservices to access Joomla functionality via JSON responses from your joomla. You can get the JSON data via jQuery in your phonegap app.

and someone said [PGBuild](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgbuild/) will convert webpage into phonegap app. You can try it also.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded creating an application as follows:

1. Design your Joomla page so it's responsive and renders correctly on your mobile;
2. Download the whole thing with wget
3. Edit all urls and make them point to the right (local-remote) locations.

I saved all css, images, js locally so the page would load even offline; then changed all the links so they point to the remote host;

All forms should point to the remote host;

Most modules and components were changed so after the initial display (local) they will load the updated info in the frame.

Popups won't be available, so you'll need heavy workarounds for facebook integration etc.
Also, if you plan to use any phonegap features, they will only be available if you load the library inside your downloaded page; this will force you to change all calls to ajax (no document.location.href calls are possible since you'll lose the phonegap javascript).

The first time you load the page from the server it will take forever to load. Ensure you have proper caching set up otherwise you'll just lose your customers.

My advice is to start with an ajax project at the very beginning, it will save you lots of headaches.

Keep in mind, if you plan to use iframes, forget it.  They work lousily on iphones, and debugging is nearly impossible.  Simply take your time to plan a real phone app in javascript & using Ajax for the calls.

You don't need any webservices in Joomla for loading content, simply use:

```
&tmpl=component
```

when you need the content of a module.

Additionally, for blogs and lists, Joomla makes RSS feeds available so you shouldn't need too much coding to achieve this.

I have limited myself to ajaxifying the modules, which makes caching more efficient on the server and the interfaces appear more dynamic.